# How do I merge two repositories with two different commits?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have come across a repository which has not been maintained for a while. Let's call it *original_repo*. I have also come across a *forked_repo* which has the required changes made to the code base which is useful for me. (The PR has not been merged yet). At the same time *original_repo* also has changes which are useful for me.

The *forked_repo* is -- *This branch is 1 commit ahead, 5 commits behind original_repo:master*

What commands do I use to have both the changes with me in my repo? I was thinking I clone the *original_repo* and then just commit changes manually by editing files from the *forked_repo*.

Comment: Just the pull request merge would solve your problem, changes in the original repo will remain as it is, and the changes on your forked repo will be merged in the original repo.

Comment: How do I get the pull request to merge? I can fork the original repo into my github, and I want the other repo changes also into my forked repo. The PR is not yet merged into the original repo, but I want it in my forked repo. FYI, the forked repo which I came across is not mine.

Comment: Wait, so do you only want to know how to do this _in GitHub_? Because I have no idea, but doing it locally with git is trivial

Answer (score 0):

You try the below steps:

1. Fork the original repo.
2. Clone the fork onto your local system.
3. Set the other forked repo as your remote. `git remote add <remote_name> <fork_url>`
4. Checkout to the branch you want to merge.
5. Merge the branch from the remote fork to your local branch. `git merge <remote_name>/<remote_branch_name>`
6. Resolve conflicts

You would get the changes from the original branch as well as the third-party fork.

Disclaimer: I have not tried this, please make sure you take suitable precautions to restore your code, in case things go wrong.